# How to perform a post to sharepoint server using nodejs http-ntlm?

Tags: node.js, post, sharepoint

I am synchronising with a Sharepoint server in a nodejs application using node-webkit...
I was able to receive the Sharepoint resources I want, using http-ntlm. However, I do not know how correctly send new resources to Sharepoint.